# Diesel Engine throwing fuel from last engine pipe when engine starts

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, accent

I have 2002 Hyundai Accent with diesel engine. It is throwing diesel from engine when gives speed. It sprays lots of oil from last diesel pipe. And in neutral when I start the engine.  Its throws a small flow of diesel. What should I do?

***Fuel leaking from fuel tubing area from last pipe***
thank you

Comment: I don't know for sure, but would bet you have a stuck injector on the cylinder which correlates with exhaust pipe. If this is the case, you can either get the injectors serviced, or replacement is always an option.